# No error printed, no output, how do I have "['p','q']" printed?

Tags: python

```
original_list = ['p','q','r','x','t','l','z','y','x','a','b']
#makes smaller list of n values, sampling from original list
def make_new_list(n, old_list):
    new_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        new_list.append(old_list[i])
        i + 1
    return new_list

print(make_new_list(2, original_list))
```

This is what I have written so far. How do I arrange or amend my code so I get '['p','q']' printed? As of now, nothing prints to the console nor any error shows up telling me what I have done wrong.

Comment: original_list[:2] ?

Comment: Increment i . Either do `i=i+1` or `i+=1`

Comment: @manvi77 Thank you. Please submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in the `while`, because you have only `i + 1`, without the assignment.

It should be: `i = i + 1`.

Also, you can use slicing for this:

```
def make_new_list(n, old_list):
    return old_list[:n]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to increment `i` variable like this:

```
i = i + 1
```

New value of `i` should be assigned to `i`.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your code I would suggest this edit:

```
original_list = ['p','q','r','x','t','l','z','y','x','a','b']
def make_new_list(n, old_list):
    new_list = old_list[:n]
    return new_list
print (make_new_list(2, original_list))
```

You can slice a list like so:

```
original_list = ['p','q','r','x','t','l','z','y','x','a','b']
new_list = original_list[:2]
```

prints:

```
['p', 'q']
```

or from the end:

```
original_list = ['p','q','r','x','t','l','z','y','x','a','b']
new_list = original_list[2:]
```

prints:

```
['r', 'x', 't', 'l', 'z', 'y', 'x', 'a', 'b']
```

or to reverse a list:

```
original_list = ['p','q','r','x','t','l','z','y','x','a','b']
new_list = original_list[::-1]
```

prints:

```
['b', 'a', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'l', 't', 'x', 'r', 'q', 'p']
```

or to slice in reverse:

```
original_list = ['p','q','r','x','t','l','z','y','x','a','b']
new_list = original_list[:-2]
```

prints:

```
['p', 'q', 'r', 'x', 't', 'l', 'z', 'y', 'x']
```

again reverse, although a bit unnecessary:

```
original_list = ['p','q','r','x','t','l','z','y','x','a','b']
new_list = original_list[-2:]
```

prints:

```
['a', 'b']
```

or to get elements not at the start:

```
original_list = ['p','q','r','x','t','l','z','y','x','a','b']
new_list = original_list[2:4]
```

prints:

```
['r', 'x']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly slice `original_list` . Refer [more on lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
In [2]: original_list[:2]
['p', 'q'] #result
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you are trying to do is simply this.

```
original_list = ['p','q','r','x','t','l','z','y','x','a','b']
print(original_list[:2])
```

which outputs `['p', 'q']`

Python array indexes start at `0` therefore to output `['p']` we would need to say `original_list[0]` and to get `['q']` would be `1`.

Since it is an array you can get the data from the first index `0` then stop just before the 3 index `2`.
`orignal_list[0:2]` would output what you want aswell.